# Find a Number of ways to Generate a Number

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have given `Fibonacci digits only` , i have to find out the numbers of ways to generate a number using `K` Fibonacci numbers only.

**Constraints:**

```
1<=K<=10
1<=N<=10^9
```

For Example:

```
N=14 and K=3
```

There are two ways:

```
(8,5,1) and (8,3,3)
```

Here is my recursive solution:

```
public static void num_gen(int i ,long val ,int used){

      if(used==0){

          if(val==n) ans++;
          return ;
      }

      if(i==Fib.length) return ;

      for(int j=0;j<=used;j++){

          long x = j*Fib[i];
          if(x+val<=n){
              num_gen(i+1,x+val, used-j);
          }
      }

}
```

This solution will timeout for large value of N and K=10. Can you provide me algorithm with better complexity.

Comment: What language is this? Please edit your question to include the correct language tag.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg updated the language tag...

Comment: So, this is an interview question or homework or...? And may I ask, if you have 3 "Fibonacci digits" what does that mean: do you have [1,1,2], [1,2,3] or apparently something containing [1,3,5,8]. Why are those four numbers all valid?

Comment: one more user wants people to make his assignment instead of him

Comment: @dlamblin When you have `K=3` you can use  only 3  Fibonacci digit...(from all the fibonacci number available on this planet ).... to make the sum equals to `N`

Comment: @user6250837 Okay, let's call numbers in the Fibonacci sequence Fibonacci numbers, a set of these as F, the sum of a set of these S, and the cardinality of all sets F is K. So the question is what is the cardinality of a set of sets F where all sets F have a cardinality of K, sum to S and contain only Fibonacci numbers <= S. It's important to know if the Fibonacci sequence in question is the original starting at 1,1 or the modern starting at 0,1. My answer assumed the former.

Answer (score 2):

This can be expressed as multiplying polynomials where exponents are Fibonacci numbers.

Number of factors is K.

The result is a coefficient of the member of the result polynomial whose exponent equals N.

Example:
What is the number of ways to compose number 7 from 3 numbers where each of these 3 numbers can be 1,2 or 3.

> (x + x² + x³)³ = x⁹ + 3x⁸ +6x⁷ + 7x⁶ + 6x⁵ + 3x⁴ + x³

Result is 6 since it is the coefficient of the x⁷ member of the result polynomial.

Comment: Can you explain with a small example? I am not able to understand it

Comment: It is a nice way to view it, but you should express it as an algorithm and state the running time.

Comment: I'm seeing 6 as the coefficient of both x<sup>7</sup> and x<sup>5</sup> but I don't see an x<sup>6</sup> in your example so your description of the result is confusing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I had a typo there. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: It could be this only works when order is important, because it's saying for the 3 that sum to 14 case [8,5,1] [5,8,1] [1,8,5] [1,5,8] etc are unique cases (x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^5 + x^8 + x^13)^3 =  1x^3 + 3x^4 + 6x^5 + 7x^6 + 9x^7 + 9x^8 + 10x^9 + 9x^10 + 12x^11 + 12x^12 + 9x^13 + 9x^14 + 10x^15 + 12x^16 + 12x^17 + 12x^18 + 12x^19 + 6x^20 + 9x^21 + 6x^22 + 9x^23 + 7x^24 + 6x^26 + 3x^27 + 3x^28 + 6x^29 + 3x^31 + 3x^34 + 1x^39 ... So pick 3 summing to 14 has 9 unique permutations of the correct 2 selections.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to give you a solution that works in another language, and I hope that helps you learn in the process of translating it to Java. Because I'm unclear on how to otherwise help you fix the recursive solution you're working on, as I believe that no recursion is required. Also no preset array of Fibonacci numbers is needed.

This is in Perl, it worked for:

```
$ perl fibber.pl 3 14
8,5,1
8,3,3
2 matches
```

But I can't guarantee it's perfectly right.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use bigint;
use List::Util qw(sum);

my ($digits, $goal) = @ARGV;
if (!($digits > 0) || !($goal > 0)) {
    die "Missing 2 arguments: the number count to sum, the value they sum to.";
}

sub fib {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    return sub {
        if (0 == scalar @_) {
            (my $r, $a, $b) = ($a, $b, $a+$b);
            return $r;
        } else {
            ($a, $b) = @_;
            (my $r, $a, $b) = ($b, $a+$b, $a+$b+$b);
            return $r;
        }
    }
}

my @f = (0) x $digits;
   @f = map {fib(1,2)} @f;
my @d = map {$_->()}   @f;
my $count = 0;
while ($d[0] < $goal) {
    if ($goal == sum @d) {
        $count++;
        print(join(",", @d)."\n");
    }
    my ($i, $a, $b) = (0, $d[$i], $f[$i]->());
    $d[$i] = $b;
    while ($goal <= $d[$i]) {
        $i++;
        if ($i == $digits) {
            print "$count matches\n";
            exit 0;
        }
        ($a, $b) = ($d[$i], $f[$i]->());
        $d[$i] = $b;
    }
    while ($i > 0) {
        $i--;
        $d[$i] = $f[$i]->($a, $b);
    }
}
```