# Find the number of ways to form an element K from an array of n elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array of `n` elements, find the number of ways in which an element `K` can be formed from these `n` elements.
For example, if the array is `{3,9,1,4,2,5}` and `K = 5`
The possible ways are:

```
1+4,
2+3,
1+2+2,
1+1+1+1+1,
1+3+1,
1+1+1+2
```

So answer should be 6.
Please suggest an algorithm for this.

Comment: What about `5` and `1+1+1+2`?

Comment: There are negatives numbers in the array?

Comment: No there are no negative numbers. And 5 is not valid but 1+1+1+2  is.

Comment: Okay, so _why_ is `5` not valid? `5` is from the given list of numbers, and the sum of `5` is `5`, obviously. Are there other important pieces of information that you are not sharing with us?

Comment: This question was asked to me in an interview. They just told what is written in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a Number of ways to Generate a Number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37110008/find-a-number-of-ways-to-generate-a-number) And there's a mathematical answer there.

Answer (score 1):

The basic algorithm looks like this:

- for every element `x` in the array:

  - if `x` is equal to `k`, then `[x]` is a solution
  - if `x` is smaller than `k`, then find the solutions for `k-x` and combine them with `x`

The easiest way to realize this in code would be as a simple recursive algorithm (here in Python):

```
def find_sums(array, k):
    for x in array:
        if x == k:
            yield [x]
        elif x < k:
            for s in find_sums(array, k - x):
                yield [x] + s
```

Note, however, that this will not be very efficient for larger arrays, as all those calls to `find_sums(array, k - x)` are repeated over and over again, but this can easily be mended with [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) or [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). Also, the result may contain some "duplicates", like `[1, 4]` and `[4, 1]`; you could either avoid those by construction (keep track of the largest element in the partial result) or filter those out afterwards (e.g., sort and convert to set). Also, if you do not want singular lists in the results, you have to filter those out, as well.

Those adjustments are left as an exercise to the reader.